# S3 roles authorization for Spark?

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark

Using pyspark2 (version 2.0.0.cloudera1) on Cloudera within AWS

I am trying to write out a dataframe from Spark to S3 storage, but failing  because of authentication:

> pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'AWS Access Key ID and
>   Secret Access Key must be specified by setting the
>   fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId and fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey properties
>   (respectively).'

My pyspark code is:

```
utp.coalesce(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save('s3n://my_bucket/tmr_xfers/test_output')
```

We use roles for accessing S3, i.e. 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/RoleName'  -- not individual AccessKeyIDs

What do I need to change in my Spark code so that my csv gets written out to S3 using roles instead of individual AccessKeyId and  SecretAccessKey?

Comment: Did you find a solution here? I have AIM set up, but I still don't get access when using s3n. Maybe I will need to use s3a.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and got around it by using `s3a://` instead, which is apparently much more modern and performant in any case.

The problem is in the Hadoop driver code (I think the `hadoop-aws.jar`) that is responsible for accessing the S3 filesystem. Apparently the `s3n` 'native' protocol uses some old jets3t driver that is difficult to work with and everyone is afraid to mess with. The new `s3a` protocol implementation uses the AWS SDK directly, and supports instance profiles etc.

Have a look at these [HADOOP-9680](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-9680) and [HADOOP-9384](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-9384) to see why they WONTFIXed this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in scala spark2, beware of security issue.

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "xxxxx")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "xxxxxxxx")
Df.write.
   format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").
   save("s3n://my_bucket/tmr_xfers/test_output")
```

Comment: This looks like you are using access key, not IAM roles. How do you use IAM roles for this?